# Stop From submission after click on form Submit

Tags: jquery

If I use forms it is automatically submitting the form. I tried to write 
ev.preventDefault().It worked first time, but the next time i click on submit second time it won't work.

```
$(document).delegate('.js-sendOffer', 'click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $('#js-createOfferForm').bootstrapValidator('validate');
  if ($('#js-createOfferForm').bootstrapValidator('isValid')) {
    $('.js-sendOffer').attr('disabled', false);
    ev.preventDefault();
    createOfferModel.createOfferSubmit(ev);
  } else {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.help-block').css('margin-left', '70px');
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code that doesn't work by updating your question?

Comment: change the button input type to `button` from `submit`

Comment: $(document).delegate('.js-sendOffer','click', function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  $('#js-createOfferForm').bootstrapValidator('validate');
  if ($('#js-createOfferForm').bootstrapValidator('isValid')) {
    $('.js-sendOffer').attr('disabled', false);
    ev.preventDefault();
    createOfferModel.createOfferSubmit(ev);
  } else {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.help-block').css('margin-left','70px');
  }
})

Comment: @VenkateshParuchuri, please add the code in by updating the question, don't post it as a comment, and add the `HTML` also.

Comment: Thankyou @Zorken17